# Dotnet Return Url Missing Parameter

Tags: javascript, .net

Here's a head-scratcher:

I have a Dotnet Application which signs a user out after a certain inactive time period. A JavaScript function using an action defined in the relevant CSHTML sends the user to a certain controller method which will sign them out.

When the JavaScript code decides that the user should be signed out, it uses the following line to do so:

```
location.href = settings.actions.expireSession + '?returnUrlString=' + currentUrl;
```

where settings.actions.expireSession is defined as:

```
expireSession: '@Url.Action("Expire", "Session")'
```

and the return url string getting into the location.href looks like this:

```
http://localhost:49574/Report/ReportWithUserIdAndCaseId?userId=84&caseId=173
```

which is correct, and the entire string assembled together with the url action looks like this:

```
"/Session/Expire?returnUrlString=http://localhost:49574/Report/ReportWithUserIdAndCaseId?userId=84&caseId=173"
```

I set up a breakpoint at the point of entry in the relevant method, but what arrives in the string parameter named "returnUrlString" there is missing the "caseId":

```
http://localhost:49574/?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49574%2FReport%2FReportWithUserIdAndCaseId%3FuserId%3D84
```

consequently, when I enter my username and password to log back in, I get redirected to the following url:

```
http://localhost:49574/Report/EntrySummaryReportWithPatientIdAndVisitId?userId=84
```

which fails because it's missing a crucial parameter.

Have I missed anything obvious? Is there something else in the automated background of Dotnet's addressing/redirection system that could be contributing to this mysterious disappearance?

A huge thanks to everyone for reading this, and a gargantuan thanks for contributors!
 - Ilia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the Url before it is sent to the Session/Expire page.

See this previous question for information on encoding it in Javascript:
[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Once you have returnUrlString on your Session Expire page, you should then unescape it and direct the user to it.

The problem is that the Url to the Session/Expire page would be:
`"/Session/Expire?returnUrlString=http://localhost:49574/Report/ReportWithUserIdAndCaseId?userId=84&caseId=173"`

What the server sees is:
Page: `"/Session/Expire?`, QueryString ReturnUrlString: `returnUrlString=http://localhost:49574/Report/ReportWithUserIdAndCaseId?userId=84`, QueryString CaseId: `&caseId=173"`

It is interpreting your &caseId as part of the /Session/Expire URL. This is why it disappears.

Comment: Thank you, Kind sir. That is what it was. For the record, I tried "encodeURI(uri)" and that failed.What worked was "encodeURIComponent(uri)".

Comment: It tends to differ based on what you want to do with it, glad this resolved your problem.